# Is this question suitable for SO or programmers?

Tags: discussion

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/252822/pulling-results-from-postgresql-with-cursors

I thought twice about posting it here as it doesn't use code as such, but after re-reading it, I think that maybe it isn't as primarily opinion as I first thought because it does have definable answers

Comment: There's certainly some opinion based parts to the question. But even if it weren't voted "Primarily Opinion Based", I think it would be closed as "Too Broad" for SO.

Answer (score 3):

It's fine on Programmers and has already picked up a reasonable answer.

Note that most activity on Programmers tends to follow the US business day with a notable exception for European business day as well.  You'll want to give it some more time and see if it picks up a few more answers.

Your question is in a grey zone where it would probably be okay on either site.  You're more likely to pick a longer, more explanatory type answer on Progs so you may want to keep it there.